# Template func and non template func call order

Tags: c++, linux, templates

In Linux I get

```
template max() is called
```

But under Windows I get

```
non-template max() is called
```

Why?  In Linux, I use gcc 4.5 and in Windows I use VS2008.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template < typename T > 
inline void max( const int& a, const T& b ) 
{
    std::cout << "template max() is called" << std::endl;
}

template < typename T > 
inline void Imax( const int& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
{
    max(a, b[0]);
}

inline void max( const int& a, const int& b ) 
{
    std::cout << "non-template max() is called" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    Imax(1, v);       
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: does the behaviour change if you move the non-template ``max`` above the declaration of ``Imax``?

Comment: Yes, when I change the max func declaration order, Under linux, got "non-template max() is called"

Comment: Good, that is what I would have expected. ``Imax`` should't be able to see the non-template ``max`` the way it is in your example.

Answer (score 4):

In pre-standard C++, you would likely get the non-template `max`.
(Without a standard, it's hard to say what you *should* get, but all of
the pre-standard compilers I know would defer name-lookup to
instantiation.)  Since C++89, you should get template `max`; name lookup
occurs in two phases: when the template is defined (at which point, only
the template `max` is visible), and when the template is instantiated,
but at the instantiation point, only for dependent names, and only using
ADL.  In your code, `max` is a dependent name, but the symbols
triggering ADL are `std::vector` (which draws in `std`) and `int`, which
doesn't add anything, not even the global namespace.  So the 
non-template `max` is not found.

These rules were among the last formalized by the C++ committee, and
compilers can't change overnight, so practically speaking, if the
compiler dates from anytime before 1995, you can probably expect the
pre-standard behavior.  For anything later, I'd tend to consider it a
compiler error, but... compilers have to support existing code, and
ideally, later compilers will have an option to use the previous name
lookup rules.  (I say ideally, because having two incompatible sets of
name lookup rules is decidedly non-trivial.  Just getting one set
correct is difficult enough for most compiler implementors.)

And it's fairly well known that Microsoft's implementation of templates
is not standard conformant, even today.

Answer (score 2):

The call of `max` in `Imax` depend on T and thus max should be searched in the template definition context (where the template max is) and combined with the argument dependent lookup in the instantiation context. ADL shouldn't find the free standing max as `int` have no associated namespace. So my take is that gcc is correct.

Note that if you have the slight variation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct S {};

template < typename T > 
inline void max( const S& a, const T& b ) 
{
    std::cout << "template max() is called" << std::endl;
}

template < typename T > 
inline void Imax( const S& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
{
    max(a, b[0]);
}

inline void max( const S& a, const S& b ) 
{
    std::cout << "non-template max() is called" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> v;
    v.push_back(S());
    Imax(S(), v);       
    return 0;
}
```

here, the global namespace is associated with S, and thus the non template max is found by the ADL lookup at the point of instantiation.

Comment: On the other hand, ADL will cause the compiler to look in `std`.  Where it might find `std::max`, which would make the call ambiguous.  (I think.)

Comment: Why would it be looked it up in std? max isn't called with vector as an argument. If you replace `max(a, b[0])` with `max(b, b)` and change the template to not to take an int, there is an ambiguity detected by g++.

Comment: Oops.  You're right.  The vector has already been dereferenced when `max` is called, and so doesn't enter into account.